# Cannot get Values from Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hello i have a gridview Naming FolderGridView. in the GridView There is a template field and inside the template field i am specifying a Linkbutton. Now i cannot get values from the linkButton in my codeBehind.

```
<asp:GridView ID="FolderGridView" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns = "False" 
        AllowPaging ="True"  OnPageIndexChanging ="FolderGridView_PageIndexChanging" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
        >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="FolderCheckBox" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>



            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Folder Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton Text='<%#Eval("File Name")%>' PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("InsideFolder.aspx?FolderName={0}",  Eval("File Name")   ) %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

my code Behind

```
for (int i = 0; i < FolderGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)FolderGridView.Rows[i].FindControl("FolderCheckBox");
        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            string FileName = (string)FolderGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text.ToString();

        }
    }
```

I have debugged the code behind portion. In FileName i get an empty string when i get to this point. How to get values from the template field then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in the cell is inside the LinkButton control, so first you have to get the LinkButton control of the GridView row, and then you can access the Text property. The following code should work in your case:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FolderGridView.Rows.Count; i++){
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)FolderGridView.Rows[i].FindControl("FolderCheckBox");
    if (chk.Checked == true){
       foreach (Control ctl in FolderGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Controls) {
           if (ctl is LinkButton) {
           string filename = ((LinkButton)ctl).Text;
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace Link Button with

EDIT:
For LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"  AutoPostBack="True"  OnClick="someMethod" Text='<%#Eval("File Name")%>' PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("InsideFolder.aspx?FolderName={0}",  Eval("File Name")   ) %>' runat="server" />
```

and code Behind

```
protected  void someMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView5.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("FolderCheckBox");
                if (chk.Checked == true)
                {

                    string probname = chk.Text;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: But i want to do it with the link button. I am trying to retrieve Text From the link button. Can i do that?